# update a specific dataframe field based on a condition involving a different field + iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (screenshot below) with a Month column and some categorical and numerical columns.
The categorical columns together form a key to define the row.

I would like to adjust some numbers such that:

1. If Obj_col3 == XY and Month == 2018-12:
   then pick the Num_col3 corresponding value and multiply by 2.
2. Then assign this Num_col3*2 to Num_col2 however at the row where the month is 2018-04 and the categorical object columns have the same combination or key as the one picked in step 1 above.
3. repeat this for each unique obj combination that you see in the dataframe.

[image]

The output dataframe :

[image]

Comment: better to provide that data as text vs. images.

Comment: You really show no effort here. No code showing what you have tried, not even **text** data that other could easily copy and paste. I am sorry, but **I** will not manually copy all that data from an image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in columns for groups, here `Obj_col1` and `Obj_col2`, then set values by conditions and last `reset_index` for original indices:

```
print (df)
   Obj_col1 Obj_col2 Obj_col3  Num_col1  Num_col2  Num_col3    Month
0         A       AB       XY        74        40        97  2018-04
1         A       AB       XY        61        26        29  2018-12
2         A       AB       XY        50        75        92  2019-03
3         A       AB       XY        33        99        87  2019-04
4         B       AB       XY        74        40         7  2018-04
5         B       AB       XY        61        26         1  2018-12
6         B       AB       XY        50        75         9  2019-03
7         B       AB       XY        33        99         8  2019-04
8         C       AB       XA        74        40         9  2018-04
9         C       AB       XA        61        26         1  2018-12
10        C       AB       XA        50        75        92  2019-03
11        C       AB       XA        33        99        87  2019-04
```

---

```
df = df.set_index(['Obj_col1','Obj_col2'])

m1 = (df['Obj_col3'] == 'XY') & (df['Month'] == '2018-12')
m2 = (df['Obj_col3'] == 'XY') & (df['Month'] == '2018-04')
df.loc[m2, 'Num_col2'] = df.loc[m1, 'Num_col3'] * 1000 # * 2 in real data 

df = df.reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
   Obj_col1 Obj_col2 Obj_col3  Num_col1  Num_col2  Num_col3    Month
0         A       AB       XY        74     29000        97  2018-04
1         A       AB       XY        61        26        29  2018-12
2         A       AB       XY        50        75        92  2019-03
3         A       AB       XY        33        99        87  2019-04
4         B       AB       XY        74      1000         7  2018-04
5         B       AB       XY        61        26         1  2018-12
6         B       AB       XY        50        75         9  2019-03
7         B       AB       XY        33        99         8  2019-04
8         C       AB       XA        74        40         9  2018-04
9         C       AB       XA        61        26         1  2018-12
10        C       AB       XA        50        75        92  2019-03
11        C       AB       XA        33        99        87  2019-04
```

Another solution with iteration, but performance is better in first solution, if large number of groups:

```
def f(x):
    m1 = (x['Obj_col3'] == 'XY') & (x['Month'] == '2018-12')
    m2 = (x['Obj_col3'] == 'XY') & (x['Month'] == '2018-04')
    x.loc[m2, 'Num_col2'] = (x.loc[m1, 'Num_col3'] * 1000).values
    return x

df = df.groupby(['Obj_col1','Obj_col2']).apply(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'objcol1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                     'objcol2': ['AB', 'AB', 'BC', 'BC'],
                     'objcol3': ['XY', 'XY', 'XY', 'XY'],
                     'numcol2': [40, 26, 96, 62],
                     'numcol3': [97, 29, 85, 11],
                     'month': pd.to_datetime(['2018-04', '2018-12', '2018-04', '2018-12'])})

# Create an index to iterative with
temp['key'] = temp['objcol1'] + temp['objcol2'] + temp['objcol3']
for k in temp['key'].tolist():
    # make two conditions to index properly
    condition_12 = (temp['key'] == k) & (temp['month'] == '2018-12-01')
    condition_04 = (temp['key'] == k) & (temp['month'] == '2018-04-01')
    # multiply and paste
    temp.loc[condition_04, 'numcol2'] = temp.loc[condition_12, 'numcol3'].values[0] * 2
```